# How to prevent duplicate rows or data in SQLite with Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-insert, not-exists

Every time I run this code, the data I insert into the table is duplicating, so how to prevent the duplication?

I tried to search for solutions but in vain. I tried to use " **if not exists** " within **INSERT INTO** as "INSERTO INTO if not exists users", but the duplication of data still exists and it doesn't work.

And I find an error says: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "not": syntax error

This is the code:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

cr = db.cursor()

cr.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists users (user_id INTEGER, name TEXT, age 
INTEGER, phone INTEGER)")

cr.execute("INSERT INTO if not exists users (user_id, name, age, phone) 
VALUES(1, 'Ahmed', 33, 01001234567)")

cr.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

 user = cr.fetchall()
 print(user)
 db.commit()
```

Comment: paste code in text format instaed of screenshot

Comment: Every time you run this code you insert the same row again. What is your question?

Comment: This is the code: `import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

cr = db.cursor()

# Create DB table of User

cr.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists users (user_id INTEGER, name TEXT, age INTEGER, phone INTEGER)")
cr.execute("INSERT INTO if not exists users (user_id, name, age, phone) VALUES(1, 'Ahmed', 33, 01001234567)")
cr.execute("SELECT * FROM users")


user = cr.fetchall()

print(user)

db.commit()`

Comment: `if not exists` what? The `user_id`? The `name`? Both? Edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a primary key in your table and set on conflict on that constraint like so :

```
create table if not exists users
( 
  user_id integer primary key not null on conflict ignore 
  , name text 
  , age integer 
  , phone integer
)
```

and now if that primary key is violated , when you insert or update nothing happens.
also quick tip  saving phone number in int  datatype is not the best practice , it's takes more memory and you are limited to numbers and etc..

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the table exists or not to create the table. But inserting the rows any ways. Please change second line as below to check first whether users table already has data with user_id 1 or not.

```
cr.execute("insert into users (user_id,name,age,phone) Select 1,'Ahmed',33,01001234567 where not exists (select 1 from users where user_id=1)")
```